# How do I verify send/recv op tensor values?

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

I'm using a parameter server and a worker. I would like to see tensor exchanges between the parameter server and the worker. I'd like to view the tensor values in send/recv nodes. Is there any logging that I can enable to view send/recv tensor values? If not, where in TensorFlow should I make modifications to view such values?